# To_number fails to convert varchar to number in update statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `test_table` as below

```
test_id varchar2(10)
new_test_id number
```

Though test_id is `varchar` it stored numbers, now I want to store the negative of the current value in test_id to new_test_id. The statement I tried is as below:

```
update test_table a set a.new_test_id = TO_NUMBER(-a.test_id);
```

This throws the invalid number error although on running a test query as

```
select TO_NUMBER(-test_id) from test_table
```

it shows properly formatted number results.

Why does `to_number` fails to convert string to number in the `update` statement where as it works fine in `select`? And what is the alternative in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out it was not working because the test_id column unexpectedly had a couple of records with alphabets. To_number was failing for only those records under update and was fine for others which had numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`update test_table a set a.new_test_id = -1 * TO_NUMBER(a.test_id);`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the minus sign *outside* the `to_number()`:

```
update test_table a set a.new_test_id = - TO_NUMBER(a.test_id);
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `a.test_id` is not getting converted to number. Still getting the error invalid number.

Comment: @Baljeet . . . I cannot think of a situation where the code would work in `select` but not in `update`.  Can you give some examples of the values in `test_id`?

Comment: I was also confused to see it work in select and not in update. Unexpectedly a couple of records had alphabets in them, and that was causing the failure.

Comment: @Baljeet . . . You can do something like `(case when REGEXP_LIKE (a.test_id, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then - TO_NUMBER(a.test_id) end)`

Answer (score 0):

```
update test_table a 
set a.new_test_id = 0 - TO_NUMBER(test_id)
```